# Can I use Groovy scripts in SoapUI to enable/disable assertions?

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertions

I'm using SoapUI Pro and a DataSource/DataSink loop to test a web service.

To make life more fun, I need to pull from four distinct source files, all of which will cause different expected results.

I'd really like to do this in a single test loop, because having scripts with multiple loops tends to crash SoapUI more often than not, but the sticking point is assertions.

How can I enable or disable assertions in a Groovy script in SoapUI? GetData doesn't give me anything to hook onto, and a documentation dive did not reveal the proper syntax. I'd assume something like testCase.assertion, but there's no such property as "assertion" on testCase.

Alternately, can I use a Groovy script to change the assertion's content? In other words, if I want phrase X with file 1, phrase Y with file 2, I'm just as happy using the same assertion, so long as I can change the content it's trying to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your Groovy script to set some kind of property `testCase.setPropertyValue('expected', 'value')`, based on which file you are reading. You could then use [property expansion](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html) `${testCase#expected#}` in the assertion content.

Comment: That will do it. Thanks!